# ggplot2 - Plot ymin and ymax as lines in stat_smooth

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm plotting a linear regression line with `ggplot2` using the `stat_smooth` function.

As expected, the function calculates the predicted value, the confidence intervals and the standard error, as written on the help page.

- y: predicted value
- ymin: lower pointwise confidence interval around the mean
- ymax: upper pointwise confidence interval around the mean
- se: standard error

The default method to plot 95% confidence interval is similar to the output of `geom_ribbon`.

I would like to plot `ymin` and `ymax` as lines, without the shaded grey area.

Is there a way to do it directly in the function? Do I have to directly access the values?

**EDIT:** the plot is a dotplot, the goal of the regression line is simply to visualize a trend. Therefore, I do not have a `lm` object. I could plot the output of a regression object, of course, but I was wondering if I could fully take advantage of the very convenient `stat_smooth` and manually set plotting parameters

Comment: In addition to the answer by @AdamQuek, you can use `stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = F) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", geom = "ribbon", fill = NA, linetype = "dashed", colour = "black")` as a work-around. However, there's no way to remove the "end caps" of the now-clear, outlined ribbon.

Comment: Thank you @Brian, that's exactly what I was looking for (but the "end caps"...). You may add it as an answer, I'll tick it

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `broom` and `ggplot2` on iris data-set:

```
fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, iris)
newd <- augment(fit)

ggplot(newd, aes(x=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Petal.Length)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted + 1.96*.se.fit), colour="blue", linetype="dotted") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=.fitted - 1.96*.se.fit), colour="blue", linetype="dotted")
```

[image]

The above is the equivalent of the `stat_smoothmethod="lm")` function:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     stat_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Adam, actually I didn't make myself clear, I apologize. I have a dotplot, I do not have a lm object. Sure I could use your approach, but I was wondering if it would be possible to directly use the very convenient  stat_smooth and to manually change the plotting parameters. I'm editing the question anyway

Comment: Since you are editing your question, please put in a reproducible example, your code and the image you have gotten at the moment. It's difficult to understand what you are trying to ask as is.